# Getting Internal Server Error after updating to RestSharp version 106.12.0

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I was previuosly working with RestSharp library version 106.2.2 to perform HTTP request in my .net project which was working fine with the below code.

```
       string endpoint = "https://api.xyz.com/api/TestControl/TestMethod?isActive=True&$top=50000&$skip=0"
       RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
          request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          request.AddHeader(
                            "Authorization",
                            string.Format(
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                          "{0} {1}",
                                          HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization.Scheme,
                                          HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization.Parameter));

        RestClient client = new RestClient
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri(endpoint),
            
        };

        IRestResponse<T> response = client.Execute<T>(request);
        return response.Data;
```

However after upgrading the restsharp version to 106.12.2 (latests stable version). I am receiving Internal Server Error for the same chunk of code. Following is the detailed exception received inside response.

```
{"$type":"ApiExceptionDto","correlationId":"8a541e5b-fa49-41d4-b2ec-671461fb1f91","developerException":null,"userException":{"$type":"ApiDetailExceptionDto","type":"SimpleException","detail":"Index must be within the bounds of the List.\r\nParameter name: index"}}
```

Comment: I don't see version 106.12.2 anywhere. Latest stable release is 106.11.7 and 106.12.2 seems to be latest release on RestSharp NuGet gallery

Comment: That was a typo. 106.12.0 seems to be latest release on RestSharp NuGet gallery

Comment: Yes, my bad!!  its a typo. Latests version is 106.12.0 which am trying to use

Comment: Have you tried in postman, to rule out the off chance the api broke ? If it works in postman, its likely time to ditch restsharp, and use the more modern flexible IHttpClientFactory

Comment: Maybe of relevance: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1621. If you can't get 106.12.0 to work, an option may simply be to go back to 106.2.2 (or another earlier version)

Comment: Kinda crazy that version 16.12.0 (as of this date) has more than 1½ million downloads, and there seems to be no release notes, no support on GitHub issues etc.
Also, you may want to go through the latest commits to master; they made some updates to CultureInfo, which I can see you use. Also authorization